# Maths related task having trouble solving using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, math

I'm having trouble solving this question, using python.

> When the middle digit of a three-digit number N is removed, the two-digit number thus obtained is N divided by 16. Find all such numbers n.

Can anyone answer the question and explain?

EDIT: The number N when divided by 16 has to equal that 2 digit number, but most of your answers don't work.

Comment: What are you stuck on? Understanding the problem? Some particular part of the code?

Comment: The fact that the question says "theree-digit" means you have a finite set of numbers to check. For each of them, perform said operation, divide by 16, and see if you get a whole number.

Comment: Why have you tagged `python-2.7` and `python-3.x`? Which one are you using?

Comment: N divided by 16 how many times?

Answer (score 2):

```
((N/100)*10+(N%10))/16
```

N/100 gets you the 10^2 digit while N%10 gets you the 10^0 digit. % stands for the modulo operator

```
for i in range(100,1000):
    if ((i/100)*10+(i%10))%16==0:
        print i
```

Comment: Could you please explain furthurmore including the 10^2 digit and what you are really calculating.

Comment: @RogerTan by 10^2 I mean the hundreds digit. In python when dividing integers say 520/100 what you get back would also be an integer so 520/100=5 and NOT 5.2. To get 5.2 you would have to type 520/100.0. What I am calculating is the hundreds digit which I am multiplying by 10 to make it the tens digit of the "new number" and I am also calculating the ones digit of the first number which is also the ones digit of the "new number".

Comment: Thanks a lot mate

Comment: What's the correct way to write this:

Comment: for num in range(99,1000):
    num2 = str(num)
    n = num2[:1] + num2[2:]
    n2 = int(n)
    if (num / 16) == n2: print (num)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to ask is how to extract a digit from a number.
how about this for 3-digits numbers:

```
N = str(N) #convert to string
N = N[:1] + N[2:] #removing 2nd digit
N = int(N) #convert to int
```

then you just have to loop over range(100:1000) and test if the number obtained can be divided by 16

Comment: How do i loop this?

Comment: for num in range(99-1000):
    num2 = str(num)
    n = num2[:1] + num2[2:]
    n2 = int(n)
    if (num / 16) == n2:
        print (num)

Why isn't this working is my syntax wrong?

Comment: for num in range(100:1000):

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do this, that for every multiple of 16 that has 2 digits, insert every digit from 0 to 9 in between those 2 digits, and append the result in a list, then you can do linear or binary search on that list for further processing, here is the code:

```
results = []

i = 1

while len(str(i*16)) == 2:

    multiple = str(i*16)
    first_digit = multiple[0]
    second_digit = multiple[1]

    for digit in range(10):
        results.append(int(first_digit + str(digit) + second_digit))

    i += 1

print("your results are: ", results)
```

The output is this:

```
your results are:  [106, 116, 126, 136, 146, 156, 166, 176, 186, 196, 302,
312, 322, 332, 342, 352, 362, 372, 382, 392, 408, 418, 428, 438, 448, 458, 
468, 478, 488, 498, 604, 614, 624, 634, 644, 654, 664, 674, 684, 694, 800, 
810, 820, 830, 840, 850, 860, 870, 880, 890, 906, 916, 926, 936, 946, 956, 
966, 976, 986, 996]
```

In this code, `i` goes from 1 to 6, and for each value of `i` the inner loop runs from `0` to `9`, thus overall iterations for getting this list of numbers is 60.

Then, depending on whether you choose to do linear search or binary search, you will have to make 60 comparisons atmost or 6 comparisons atmost respectively.

Hope this helps.

Comment: From what I understand, your reply does not fit wiht the expected answer. If we call S, the 2 digit-number and N the original number. You should find all N where S = N/16

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, if we call S the number given by the first and last digit of N. You are looking for all N where S = N/16.
I solve it with the following solution :

```
i = 7 # first i where i*16 > 100

while i*16 < 1000:
    N_num = i * 16
    N = str(N_num)
    S = N[0] + N[-1]
    S_num = int(S)
    if S_num == N_num/16:
        print(N_num)
    i += 1
```

Answer:

- 160 (S = 10 and 10*16 = 160 = N)
- 192 (S = 12 and 12*16 = 160 = N)